# DJANGO: JSONDecodeError at /folderName/ Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, django

Update: issue resolved. I needed to specify the super folder so i changed `'data.json'` to read `'folderName/data.json'`

Django 2.1.2
Python 3.6

I keep getting a JSONDecodeError when I'm trying to load a Json file in my views.py.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import json

def index(request):

    with open('data.json') as data:
        args = json.loads(data.read())

    return render(request, 'folderName/index.html', args)
```

data.json

```
{"number2":{
    "type":"Holiday",
        "content": [
    {"name":"New Year's Day", "month":1, "day":1},
    {"name":"Martin Luther King Jr. Day", "month":1, "day":21},
    {"name":"National Wear Red Day", "month":2, "day":1},
    {"name":"Groundhog Day", "month":2, "day":2},
    {"name":"Valentine's Day", "month":2, "day":14},
    {"name":"Presient's Day", "month":2, "day":18},
    {"name":"Employee Appreciation Day", "month":3, "day":1},
    {"name":"Daylight Savings Time", "month":3, "day":10},
    {"name":"St. Patrick's Day", "month":3, "day":17},
    {"name":"Good Friday", "month":4, "day":19},
    {"name":"Easter Sunday", "month":4, "day":21},
    {"name":"Cinco De Mayo", "month":5, "day":5},
    {"name":"Mother's Day", "month":5, "day":12},
    {"name":"Memorial Day", "month":5, "day":27},
    {"name":"Flag Day", "month":6, "day":14},
    {"name":"Father's Day", "month":6, "day":16},
    {"name":"Independence Day", "month":7, "day":4},
    {"name":"Labor Day", "month":9, "day":2},
    {"name":"Columbus Day", "month":10, "day":14},
    {"name":"Halloween", "month":10, "day":31},
    {"name":"Daylight Savings Time", "month":11, "day":3},
    {"name":"Vetern's Day", "month":11, "day":11},
    {"name":"Thanksgiving Day", "month":11, "day":28},
    {"name":"Black Friday", "month":11, "day":29},
    {"name":"Cyber Monday", "month":12, "day":2},
    {"name":"Pearl Harbor Rembrance Day", "month":12, "day":7},
    {"name":"Christmas Eve", "month":12, "day":24},
    {"name":"Christmas Day", "month":12, "day":25},
    {"name":"New Year's Eve", "month":12, "day":31}
    ]
}}
```

It will decode in a separate py file when I have the same code that is ran through idle.

```
import json

with open('data.json') as data:
        args = json.loads(data.read())
```

edit 1: as requested I'm adding the full traceback I hope this helps. I could always use a sql database, but I figured it would be easier to edit a json file if I need to append more data too it.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/AnkenyIA/

Django Version: 2.1.2
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['folderName',
 'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File 
"C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py" 
in raw_decode
  355.             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

During handling of the above exception (0), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
request)

File "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\$user\Desktop\mysite\mysite\folderName\views.py" in index
  7.         data = json.load(file)

File 
"C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py" 
in load
  299.         parse_constant=parse_constant, 
object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

File 
"C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py" 
in loads
  354.         return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File 
"C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py" 
in decode
  339.         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File 
"C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py" 
in raw_decode
 357.             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) 
from None

Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /folderName/
    Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: for the given json, I could not find any issue with `json.loads()`

Comment: Can you post the error trace?

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?  You may need to specify a path to the json file.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Your comment fixed the issue. Thank you so Much!